# error when Trying to read State Names using string tokenizer

Tags: java, javascript

This program allows a user to calculate to enter sales and calculate sales taxes per state.
The program is giving errors when it gets to reading the double word states (eg New Jersey).I need helo with part.

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.awt.*;
//import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.lang.model.type.ArrayType;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
public class PJ5 extends JFrame implements ListSelectionListener
{String []States = new String[100];
    double []statetax = new double[100];
double sales;
JPanel p1;
JList  StateList;



JTextField salesField;
private JTextField taxField;
public static void main(String []args)    
  {
  PJ5  x = new PJ5();
  x.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  x.setTitle("Sales tax calculator");
  x.setSize(350, 250);
  x.setVisible(true);

  } // main

public PJ5() // constructor
{
String s;
StringTokenizer st;
int k=0;
try 
{
BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\taxrates.txt"));
    while ((s= inFile.readLine()) != null)
    {


st = new StringTokenizer(s);
        States[k]=(st.nextToken());

    statetax[k] = Double.valueOf(st.nextToken());

    ++k;
    } // while not EOF
  inFile.close();
} catch (Exception e) { System.err.println(e); }



JPanel p1 =new JPanel();

 p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

p1.add(new JLabel("Sales amount:"));
salesField= new JTextField(5);
salesField.setEditable(true);
p1.add(salesField);


p1.add(new JLabel("tax:"));
taxField= new JTextField(4);
taxField.setEditable(false);
p1.add(taxField);


add(p1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
pack();
setVisible(true);

JPanel p = new JPanel();
StateList = new JList(States);  // create a JList object
StateList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); 
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(StateList);  // adding scrolling capability
p.add(sp);
getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
// Event registration
StateList.addListSelectionListener(this);
} // constructor

// Event handling
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event)
     {
    DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("0.00");   
    double tax;
     sales=Double.parseDouble(salesField.getText());

tax=sales* (statetax[StateList.getSelectedIndex()]/100);
     taxField.setText("$"+dollar.format(tax));

     } // valueChanged
}
```

here is the text file with the states en their tax rates.

```
Alabama 4.0
Alaska 0.
Arizona 5.6
Arkansas 6.0
California 8.25
Colorado 2.9
Connecticut 6.0
Delaware  2.07
Florida 6.0
Georgia 4.0
Hawaii 4.0
Idaho 6.0
Illinois 6.25
Indiana 7.0
Iowa    6.0
Kansas  5.3
Kentucky    6.0
Louisian,   4.0
Maine   5.0
Maryland    6.0
Massachusetts   6.25
Michigan    6.0
Minnesota   6.875
Mississippi 7.0
Missouri    4.225
Montana 0.
Nebraska    5.5
Nevada  6.85
New Hampshire 0.0
New Jersey  7.0
New Mexico  5.375
New York    4.0
North Carolina  4.5
North Dakota    5.0
Ohio    5.5
Oklahoma    4.5
Oregon  0.
Pennsylvania    6.0
Rhode Island    7.0
South Carolina  6.0
South Dakota    4.0
Tennessee   7.0
Texas   6.25
Utah    5.95
Vermont     6.0
Virginia    5.0
West Virginia   6.0
Wisconsin   5.0
Washington  6.5
Washington DC   5.75
Wyoming 4.0
```

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Hampshire"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because, the tokenizer parses **New** as a string then the next code parses **Hampshire** as a double, you may need to restructure your code

Comment: Done.But still My scroll pane only shows states with single words.still giving me java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Hampshire".

Comment: Try changing the `0.` after `Hampshire` to `0.0`.

Comment: Yeah I did that.its still reading the NEW and living out the Hampshire.its doing the same for all the double word states like New jersey,south carolina.so i think its  States[k]=(st.nextToken()); that i need to change only I tried changing en it gives me more errors!

Comment: @user1011194 String tokenizer reads strings after each whitespace. If you can separate them with a comma `,` then use `StringTokenizer(s, ",");` then it should work well.

Comment: Ok so i separated the state names with commas.but adding the StringTokenizer(s, ","); gives the error and it only reads the first states.Thanks for your effort."java.util.NoSuchElementException"

Comment: I'm talking, using `st = new StringTokenizer(s,",")` in the while loop!

Comment: its gal.:) ok if you run the program its only suppose to read the state NAME not the tax rate.thats how i made it.so my focus was reading the double word states.:).iam reading the taxrate and only using it to calculate sales tax.the only thing showing on the scroll pane is the state Name!

Comment: yes that is it.en that is wat am getting right now.but if you notice wen u scroll down the states that are double worded are not being read(new Hampshire).but waht i have done now is i got rid of the spaces between double word states.and i created another program that doesnt use strign tokenizer .ill compare the two and check which one i can go with.thanks! en i read that string tokenizer delimits the spaces so maybe i shoud use inFile.readLine.am gona try it!

Comment: hey Mob u were right.i added this (s,",") but i also had to change this st = new StringTokenizer(s,",");
       
     States[k]=Sring.valueOf(st.nextToken()); thanks a zillion.
     
i had to read states as string  en not as States[k]=(st.nextToken());

Comment: @user1011194 no probs! :) You can accept the answer by clicking ✔